# Mixing inline and macro functions

Tags: c++, macros, inline

I've decided to try something. I know macros are evil and should be avoided but wanted to see what's going to happen if I do such a thing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
inline void add(int x, int y) { cout << "Inline: " << x + y << endl; }
#define add(x,y) ( cout << "Macro: " << x + y << endl )

int main()
{
    add(3,5);
}
```

It outputs:

```
Macro: 8
```

If I comment out the `#define` line inline starts working, and the output turns into `Inline: 8`.

My question is, why compiler decides to use macro function instead of inline. Thank you!

> I'm using `Linux Mint 18.2`, `g++ 5.4.0`, with no parameters `g++ -g t2.cpp -o t2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro substitution is performed via the pre-processor *before*  compilation. Thus the compiler never sees `add(3,5)` - it only sees the macro expansion.

Comment: Oh, so that's why when there's a `#define` around it ignores `inline`. Because it `#define` replaces the `add(3,5)`. Thank you! I'll accept your answer 10 minutes later. Since stackoverflow limits the time on it.

Comment: The compiler does not "ignore inline" - it doesn't see the `add(3,5)` function call at all, so it cannot call the `add` function, inline or not.

Answer (score 2):

A macro comes to effect **at the place it is defined**, so the inline function is *not* replaced by the macro, but your call is replaced before compilation. Also note that a macro is *not* a function, it tells the **preprocessor** a pattern of replacing texts.

You can run the following command and see the output file (`your.i`)

```
g++ -o your.i -E your.cpp
               ^
```

And you'll find the inline function not affected by the macro :)

Option `-E` for G++ means "preprocess the source file, but don't compile, don't assemble and don't link".

Comment: Okay... that's interesting. Everyday I learn something new. Thank you iBug! I've understood what's going on at the Neil Butterworth's answer. Now, I know how to see the output file! **Edit:** Thanks for the extra effort on explaining me what's `-E` flag.

Comment: I've tried the -E and it outputted a file that's 18166 lines long. Is it normal? o_o

Answer (score 2):

There is not such thing as "macro function". Compiler (actually preprocessor) just turns `main` into

```
int main()
{
    ( cout << "Macro: " << 3 + 5 << endl );
}
```

Comment: I didn't know the name of it. Sorry, but why does it choose the macro instead?

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman Preprocessor runs before compiler and replaces all the macro invocation with their bodies. So when compiler actually starts compiling there is no `add` call there anymore.

Comment: Thank you @VTT. Now I've understood it better!